# In which case could be useful git checkout --orphan?

Tags: git

I found out that there is a possibility to create an orphan branch `git checkout --orphan` and as far as I understood this command will create a branch that has no history, but I just trying to think in which case could it be useful? Why do I need to create such kinds of branches?

Comment: To start a new history, unrelated to existing commits, such as when you want to pretend a certain branch or certain commits have never existed. Have you tried searching?

Comment: @CodeCaster my question was about `in which case it could be useful` have you tried to read the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One example is that when I want to torch the history of a branch, I would create an orphan branch from its current state, and create the root commit for force-pushing.

It's easy to understand why. For example, I use GitHub Actions to deploy my static website onto GitHub Pages, and when there's too many history bloating the repository, I would "reset" the deployment branch and torch its history, since that branch contains solely of program-generated content (the built website).